# Facebook login with Javascript & ASP.NET Web API

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, facebook-login

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around Facebook login coupled with my api security-wise for a webapp I'm creating. What do I need to store in my database, ID, token, something hashed etc? My flow so far is as follows:

1. When a user visit my app they see a welcome text with a button saying "Login with Facebook".
2. They hit the Facebook-button, if the user do not exist a new row is created in the database. For now I'm storing the user's Facebook name, id and a hashed token with the combination of the two. And then store a cookie with the token.
3. If the user return later to visit the app, they get redirected to the app without going through the Facebook login, because the token is stored in the cookie, and the user is found in the database based on it.
4. If the user return to the app without a the cookie token. The user has to hit the login with Facebook-button again, but now the user exist in the database and based on the name and id, I can find the user and return the token for a cookie.

Step 4 however seem a bit unsecure. Based on the name and id I can find a token of a user and set it in my cookie, granted I know (or can find?) the name and the id of that user I want to exploit.

This is my flow. Am I approaching this wrong, do I have to use the Facebook SDK C# in my Web API for server-side validation regarding a access token of some sort?

Any tips, hints or pointers to another flow is very welcome aswell.

Here is my desired flow: [image]